# PHP form handling with post prints nothing

Tags: php, html

I am trying check if username or email already exists . This is my form

```
<form role="form" action="kys_SignUp.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                                         <label for="email" >Email address:</label>
                                         <input type="email" style="width: 300px" class="form-control"  name="email" id="email" required>
                    </div>

             <div class="form-group">
                                         <label for="Username" >Username:</label>
                                         <input type="text" style="width: 300px" class="form-control" name="username" id="Username" required>
                    </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                                         <label for="password" >Password:</label>
                                         <input type="password" style="width: 300px" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required>
                    </div>

                   <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

            </form>
```

I am sending the data in Post Method. My server side script looks like this

```
<?php 

 include "kys_DbConnect.php";

$email = $username = $password = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    $email = cleanData($_POST["email"]);
    $username = cleanData($_POST["username"]);
    $password = cleanData($_POST["password"]);


}



    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM kys_users WHERE username=? OR email=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$username,$email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$email,$username,$password);
     $stmt->fetch();

    if($username == ""){

       header("Location : http://localhost/KeyStroke/index.html ");
        exit();
    }  
   else{

        echo "Username or Email already exists";

   }



function cleanData($data){

    $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;

}



?>
```

This is my kys_DbConnect.php

```
 <?php
     $serverName = "localhost";
    $username = "jois";
    $password = "iluvcoding";
    $db_name = "kys_userdata";    

    $con = new mysqli($serverName,$username,$password,$db_name);



    if($con->connect_error){

        echo "Connection Error";

    }
?>
```

I don't know why but it print's nothing nor redirects to index.html (index.html exists). How can I figure out what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Show kys_DbConnect.php

Comment: I did  now . check it out

Comment: Insted of checking for empty use `if(isset($username)){`

Comment: thankyou but it print's Username already exists even if the username doesnt exist! what wrong. that means isset($username) returns false

Comment: when does it return false?? when username is not empty??

Comment: try putting these at the very top of your script right after `<?php` to see if any errors show up on the page: `error_reporting( -1 ); ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );`

Comment: Remove $email = $username = $password = ""; And include everything up to cleandata in the `if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")` condition

Comment: @Mihai if i remove that line i wouldnt be able access these variables throught the script. so i change $username in bind_result to $kys_username

Comment: You dont need to initialize variables in php,they are already set after the if(or should be)

Comment: Thanks its working